# Mixing PHP and ASP.NET under same domain

Tags: php, asp.net, iis-7

How PHP mixes with ASP.NET ? Let's say I have an asp.net app under root domain. Then I create a folder where I will put PHP.

Can PHP live under ASP.NET without problem ? Is it necessary that I transform PHP dir into an app under IIS7 ?

PHP is installed. My question is about adding a PHP app under an ASP.NET app not under IIS in general.

Comment: You should create a virtual directory in your website for php stuff and point the virtual directory to a folder which exists in some other location outside the asp.net app root folder.

Comment: Can you explain what difference does it make for asp.net web config ?

Comment: No changes required in web.config, you need to just add virtual directory in IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET and PHP will happily co-reside in the same website. From your comments you are asking if it is ok to put your PHP application in a folder of its own and turn this into an application. Yes that is perfectly fine to do.

Just make sure that you've configured PHP properly which means running a non-threadsafe build of PHP using FastCGI:

> [Using FastCGI to Host PHP Applications on IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-7/)

That is the recommended way to run PHP on IIS6 and IIS7 now.

Answer (score 2):

PHP will run quite merrily on IIS.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis.php

From my experience, I'd advise creating a different AppPools for PHP / .NET.

Comment: PHP is installed. My question is about adding a PHP app under an ASP.NET ap

Comment: different app pools - that's not needed if you've correctly configured IIS7 to serve PHP pages via fastcgi.

Comment: Point well made. If you're blessed with a IIS5 production environment (and no chance of installing FastCGI flavour), would recomend above.

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible. you can run php script in IIS

Here is the link

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/24/running-php-applications-on-iis/

All the best. :)

Comment: PHP is installed. My question is about adding a PHP app under an ASP.NET app not under IIS in general.