# How to redirect website without affecting blog?

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, url-rewriting, url-routing

I'm running an Asp.Net (4.0) website. There also a Wordpress blog on the same machine.

The blog is a folder under the main domain: www.mydomain/blog/

Here is the problem.

I've just been doing some page analysis and discovered that link juice is being split between pages with a trailing slash and pages without a trailing slash.

I found the code to remove the trailing slash (my preferred option) and added it to my web config - it which works on the main site but causes problems with Wordpress.

```
    <rule name="Remove trailing slash">
      <match url="(.*)/$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

The code isn't the problem. Asp.Net routing in (4.0) creates routes without a trailing slash - Wordpress on the other hand, creates routes with a trailing slash - therefore implementing the code in my main web.config causes a loop problem. I'm also worried about the SEO affects.

Is there a way I can modify the above code so that it kicks in for the main site and not for the blog?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is WP `Php`?. If so, check [if this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5701734/304683). Although I've never done the above in practice, I would think _application scope_  should still be in play - re: let ASP.net only handle ASP.net (separate application scopes). Hth...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line of xml into the conditions:

```
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" 
     matchType="Pattern" 
     pattern="/blog/$" 
     negate="true" />
```

It should tell the redirect to not fire if it ends in `/blog/`

Comment: sorry, I think i misread your question. Does wordpress give you urls like: `mysite.com/blog/post-1/`? If so, change the pattern to this: `/blog/.+/$`, because the current pattern only prevents urls ending in `/blog/`, but that doesn't help you if your url pattern is different. The solution in general is to say to IIS: "only redirect if my url does not look like a wordpress url", whatever those urls look like.

Comment: Thanks welegan - I'll give a go at the first opportunity